# Playing An Audio File Through An App

Tags: iphone

Is there anyway to store audio on an iphone app and then grab that audio file and play it through code. Does anyone have a tutorial to point me to do something like this?

Comment: Um have you looked through the sample code on Apple's site. Its also installed with the SDK on your computer. It has a handful of samples for playing audio different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the AVAudioPlayer class here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW1

Should tell you what you need to know.